# VueJS prevent default action on custom event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<btn>` component which consists of the following template:

```
<button @click="$emit('trigger')">
</button>
```

I use the component in my forms like this:

```
<btn>Submit</btn>
```

Now there are situations when I need to have two buttons in the form. One of them submits the form, and the other does not. But because both of them are inside my form, they both submits the form. I cannot do something like this:

```
<btn>Submit</btn> <!-- This button should submit the form -->
<btn @trigger="nextQuiz">Next</btn> <!-- This button should only execute the nextQuiz method -->
```

How can I tell vue to to prevent the form submission only when the second `<btn>` is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

```
Vue.component("btn",{
  props:{
    submit: Boolean
  },
  computed:{
    type() { return this.submit ? 'submit' : 'button' }
  },
  template: `
    <button :type="type"  @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>
  `
})
```

Used like:

```
<form action="">
  <btn submit>Submit</btn>
  <btn>Don't Submit</btn>
</form>
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("btn",{
  props:{
    submit: Boolean
  },
  computed:{
    type() { return this.submit ? 'submit' : 'button' }
  },
  template: `
    <button :type="type"  @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="">
    <btn submit>Submit</btn>
    <btn>Don't Submit</btn>
  </form>
</div>
```

@thanksd had a similar other idea to one I had. You could also use the prevent modifier.

```
Vue.component("btn",{
  props:{
    submit: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <button v-if="submit" @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>
    <button v-else="submit" @click.prevent="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You could specify inline to prevent the default behavior of the native click event via `@click.native.prevent`:

```js
Vue.component('btn', {
  template:`
    <button @click="$emit('trigger')">
      <slot/>
    </button>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    nextQuiz() {
      console.log('nextQuiz')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="">
    <input name="bar">
    <btn>Submit</btn>
    <btn @click.native.prevent @trigger="nextQuiz">Next</btn> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The native modifier is now deprecated in vue 3

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provide alternative solutions i.e. how to make it so that you *don't need to prevent the default action* -- but to address the actual question of **how to prevent the default action via a custom event**...

You can pass the native click event through to your custom event using the [special $event variable](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers):

<button @click="$emit('trigger', ***$event***)">

And then you can receive that event in your custom nextQuiz method and call preventDefault to prevent the native behaviour:

```
<btn @trigger="nextQuiz">Next</btn>

...

nextQuiz(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your root element is a `button` (which is in your case), you could also set the type to button, which will pass through to the button. `<button type="button">Click</button>` natively doesn't submit forms. In your case, `<btn type="button">Click</btn>` should not submit the form. This keeps your Vue code simpler.

```html
<btn>Submit</btn> <!-- This button should submit the form -->
<btn type="button" @trigger="nextQuiz">Next</btn> <!-- This button should only execute the nextQuiz method -->
```

See [MDN on button type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) and the [HTML Spec for buttons](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element).